# How can I boot to Safari Only (Chromebook style) in Lion?

Tags: macos, startup, safari

How can I boot safari only in Mac OSX Lion Chrome OS style? I heard that there was a key that one had to hold at startup, which one is it?

Comment: It's not yet clear how or whether that feature from beta made the final cut. The recovery console isn't really chrome os style since although it has a browser, it can easily erase the mac without a password (or reset the admin password) - not what you would want to hand over to a friend.

Comment: Have a look at this thread:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19705/how-do-i-disable-safari-only-mode
Here is a user who has this feature turned on on his machine, but wants to disable it. I wonder if there is a hidden setting.

Comment: Yes, or maybe that using was using the developer version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this. There are two types of Guest User mode in Lion:

a) Safari-only mode: This is the default setting if *no Guest account is enabled*. Therefore to turn this on, go to System Preferences / Users and Groups / Guest User, then *uncheck* "Allow guests to log in to this account".

- Note: Under "Login Options", "Display login window as:" must be set to "List of Users" or this will not work.

b) Snow Leopard-like Guest Account - a full guest account as in previous versions of OS X. This mode is enabled when "Allow guests to log in to this account" is checked.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the Safari-only mode was not included in the retail build of OS X Lion.

Comment: Not true! See my answer for a resolution to this.

Answer (score 0):

**Command-R** will boot into the recovery partition. Once booted you can launch Safari as described on the feature page.

```
The Recovery HD includes the Safari web browser so you can check your email or 
browse the Apple Support site.
```

Source: http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/features.html#lionrecovery

Comment: That's not what the question is asking. Odinulf is asking about [this](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2011/06/lions-safari-only-mode-offers-nice-alternative-to-guest-accounts.ars)

Comment: @Nathan ... did you just read Odinulf's mind or is Odinulf your sock puppet? *Putting tin foil hat on* Odinulf asked which key to hold at start up, he didn't ask about a restart in Safari mode button...

Comment: @steve haha, just a mind read I guess. Ah, recovery mode contains Safari mode? That's news to me, thanks!

Comment: @Nathan, impressive. Is anyone else seeing the quoted text cutoff? Any ideas as to why it is happening?

Comment: @Steve scrolls for me. If you're on Lion, you may not be seeing the scroll bar. Try scrolling to the side anyway.

Comment: I am in fact a magical sock puppet.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet. It is a part of Find My Mac, which is a part of iCloud. 
Once Find My Mac is enabled & a user account is logged in, but at the login screen, you have the option to boot to Safari-Only mode. Once iCloud is released, it should be available (unless, of course, Apple decides to remove it), but not something you'd really want to do.

Answer (score -1):

Noah has it right, it is currently part of iCloud, and unless you have downloaded and installed the iCloud beta software, and signed in with an iCloud ID, AND turned on back to my mac in the preferences area for iCloud, it will not appear as an option.