# How do I disable Safari-only mode?

Tags: macos, safari

I have no desire to enable Lion's Safari-only mode. I have disabled the guest account but still see the guest login item when I reboot my system.

Is there a setting somewhere I'm missing for disabling the Safari-only mode?

Comment: I can't find that feature at all - maybe because I performed a clean install. See here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17924/how-can-i-boot-to-safari-only-chromebook-style-in-lion

Comment: There is no "Safari-only mode" except as the emergency browser in the recovery partition.

In answering this I am assuming you want to turn off the standard Guest user account.

Comment: Incorrect. I have "Guest" on the login screen, and the Guest account under System Prefs is set to disabled. When I select Guest from the login screen it tells me that the system will restart into this mode with only Safari.

Comment: I also performed a clean install.

Comment: How odd. On my machine, when Guest account is disabled the "Guest" option on the log in screen is removed. It seems that you have an extra feature to the rest of us!

Comment: So you are experiencing this feature?
http://www.tuaw.com/2011/06/13/lions-restart-to-safari-feature-allows-macs-to-act-as-web-onl/
Can you please outline how you activate it? As I understood, it was enabled in the dev previews but absent from the released version of Lion.

Comment: @Bryson, James' answer works, letting you have Find My Mac and not the Guest/Safari account.

Comment: I was incorrect to say that there is no "Safari-only mode"! I have just realised that this mode is only enabled if you (paradoxically) have the Guest account *disabled* in settings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can disable the Guest account at startup in System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Advanced (the button at the bottom of the screen. The checkbox says "Disable restarting to Safari when screen is locked". I believe that it leaves the iCloud settings unchanged.

[image]

This works without changing iCloud.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Damn Apple for hiding it away :) (btw the option only appears when Find My Mac is enabled, and you may have to fully quit settings and reopen it for it to appear)

Answer (score 9):

This guest account is tied in with iCloud's Find My Mac service in System Preferences. If you disable that service, the Safari-only mode (and the subsequent Guest account on the login screen) will also be disabled.

Comment: This sucks, along with no iCloud for iWork on Mac.

Comment: They will resolve that issue eventually. Note: The lack of iCloud support on OS X iWork.

Comment: Actually, this did not change anything for me. Still there on login screen.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can disable it wihtout disabling 'find my iphone' by following steps in [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2011/10/13/disable-guest-user-account-mac-os-x-10-7-2-login-screen/). I doubt that 'find my iphone' will be much use though if the person who steals it can't login, but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Guest account should disappear when you disable it, (i.e. when you uncheck Allow guests to login to this computer) so your settings must have become slightly corrupted.

To fix them, try reenabling Guest account in the settings, rebooting, then disabling guest account.

Answer (score -1):

to disable Safari-only mode and the guest account go to
system preferences
iCloud
and then uncheck  (Find My Mac) <--  thats mean you will disable this fissility .
Reboot

Thats all
GL