# Can Find My Mac be disabled on a stolen MacBook without a password?

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, find-my-mac, security

My friend had his MacBook stolen from his house but he didn't have a password on his MacBook so if the thief logged out of his iCloud can it still be tracked since he already put a lock on it?

If he deletes the iCloud account while the MacBook isn't connected to Wi-Fi can he still track it if the MacBook connects to Wi-Fi?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lost my Macbook pro with retina display. How do I find out if Find My iDevice is enabled on it?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80394/lost-my-macbook-pro-with-retina-display-how-do-i-find-out-if-find-my-idevice-is)

Answer (score 2):

1. No, not without the original password
2. No, but you can sign into your icloud account from a different device and track the computer

Answer (score 1):

> Can Find My Mac be disabled on a stolen MacBook without a password?

Yes, it could be done also on MacBook with account password.

If you don't have configured a password to choose boot options the thief is able to delete all your content, without having your root password.
He can simply:

1. Do not connect your Mac in internet.
2. Turn on Mac pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to enter in CLI mode.
3. Change your admin account password (I have intentionally omitted details on this step).
4. Logout.
5. Login using your account with his password.
6. Disable all services related to iCloud, so disable Find My Mac.

In this case you're unable to locate your Mac and the thief is also able to reinstall from zero the Mac OS X.

Comment: What is this 'boot option' thing? How to cofigure a password to choose boot options?

Answer (score 0):

If your device is built on T2 Apple security chip you can bypass the Find My Mac activation lock. This method build on CheckM8 exploit. You can use CheckM8 Software. Firstly, it works on any Mac devices with the T2 security chip, which protects Mac OS computers from unauthorized startups. Secondly, it requires no Apple ID or password for the successful bypass of Mac Activation Lock. This tool bypass this Activation Lock by skipping the activation step on the computer hardware, which the T2 chip controls.

Comment: Does this bypass enabling FMM or does it disable it after it had been set previously?